# Global Variables Xcode

Tags: xcode

Hi I have a relative strange Problem and it costs me a lot of nerves :-)

I have a *.h file with content of

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
```

I synthized it also in the *.m file

```
@synchronized name;
```

Works great but I have a (void) Function in my code which writes a string into Variable name like:

```
name = @"Test";
```

And in an `IBAction` of a button I would like to use the stored string of name but name is empty in the `IBAction` part.

in the IBAction

```
NSlog(@"%@",name);
```

What are my problems?

Maybe someone can help.

Comment: Are you sure that your void function is being called prior to the `IBAction`?  Are the methods being called on the same instance of the class?

Comment: yes. hmm Really tricky !